# Java while loop dramatically slows down over time after a large number of iterations

Tags: java, while-loop, time-complexity

My program reads a text file line by line in a while loop. It then processes each line and extracts some information to be written in the output. Everything it does inside the while loop is O(1) except two ArrayList indexOf() method calls which I suppose are O(N). The program runs at a reasonable pace (1M lines per 100 seconds) in the beginning but over time it slows down dramatically. I have 70 M lines in the input file so the loop iterates 70 million times. In theory this should take about 2 hours but in practice it takes 13 hours. Where is the problem?

Here is the code snippet:

```
BufferedReader corpus = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream("MyCorpus.txt"),"UTF8"));

Writer outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), "UTF-8"));

List<String> words = new ArrayList();
//words is being updated with relevant values here   

LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> DIC = new LinkedHashMap();
//DIC is being updated with relevant key-value pairs here    

String line = ""; 
while ((line = corpus.readLine()) != null)
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    if (DIC.containsKey(parts[0]) && DIC.containsKey(parts[1])) {

        int firstIndexPlusOne = words.indexOf(parts[0])+ 1;
        int secondIndexPlusOne = words.indexOf(parts[1]) +1;

        outputFile.write(firstIndexPlusOne +" "+secondIndexPlusOne+" "+parts[2]+"\n");
        } else { 
            notFound++;
            outputFile.write("NULL\n");
        }
    }
outputFile.close();
```

Comment: There is room for lots of optimization - If you know `parts` is always a two-element array, you should use `indexOf(' ')` and split with `substring`, so you have two variables `part1` and `part2`. - ***EDIT***: Overlooked the `parts[2]` - but it also works for three elements.

Comment: corpus has 70 M lines each comprising three words. Just updated the code.

Comment: I'd say it depends - besides JVM runtime optimization magic, garbage collector and such - on the actual file content? If, e.g., in the first 10M lines the containsKey is never true, but for the remaining 60M it evaluates to true, the whole file writing business is executed only then, which takes a lot of time. Big-O-considerations are probably of little help here, since even I/O is involved. Perhaps you could include a counter which counts and/or outputs which lines of code are executed for which lines of your file?

Comment: Is DIC is updated somehow in a loop ? Also, what's the length of words ?

Comment: I think you will find out that 99% (probably way more) of the runtime is consumed by performing I/O, so it boils down to when the file writing is executed, which depends entirely on the file's contents.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code? Neither "words" nor "DIC" seem to be updated.

Comment: @JFP, Diego, no DIC is only read in the loop. Length of words is 1M. I intentionally didn't put the update part (just the relevant comments) for the sake of simplicity. Just assume they are populated with some string values.

Comment: @ stef77, I did a rough evaluation and figured that the largest portion of time is consumed by indexOf() method calls. Maybe using BufferedWriter makes the I/O quite fast?

Comment: @Meghi Ah, ok, that sounds reasonable - probably the BufferedWriter writes to a String internally anyway so there's not much I/O - if it doesn't decide when it's filled up enough to actually start writing really to the file, which could be an explanation for the slowdown by the way. How did you evaluate that indexOf is the most time consuming part? Without real profiling, that should be rather hard to tell? But if it is, using sorting as suggested by OldCurmudgeon should of course help.

Comment: Have you examined CPU utilization as the process slows down? If it is/falls under 100% (one CPU core), I/O would be seem to be a more likely cause. Otherwise try using a tool like jconsole to get more insight. Watch memory allocation / garbage collection as well as CPU utilization for changes over time.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you add words to your `words` `ArrayList` as you go.

You correctly state that `words.indexOf` is `O(N)` and that is the cause of your issue. As `N` increases (you add words to the list) these operations take longer and longer.

To avoid this keep your list sorted and use [binarySearch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29).

To keep it sorted use `binarySearch` on each word to work out where to insert it. This takes your complexity from `O(n)` to `O(log(N))`.

Comment: Wouldn't one likely reason that the comment `//words is being updated with relevant values here` suggests that `words` is being built beforehand, before the loop runs, and is then not updated within the loop? What sense would it make to write out the index of a constantly changing collection into the results file? After all, obtaining these index numbers seems to be the whole use case? Of course, that's just my interpretation, only @Meghi might answer this for sure.

Comment: stef77 is right. words is being updated outside the loop and doesn't change afterwards. I think you are right and the major problem is with indexOf() method. As far as I have seen even I/O is not as time consuming. So you are suggesting I write my own indexOf method on a sorted list that uses binary search? words contain String values. I wonder how would binary search work for that.

Comment: @Meghi - Ok so sort it. binarySearch *assumes* the list is sorted. Just sort the list once it is built and use `binarySearch` instead of `indexof` - it returns the location in the list just like `indexof`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon - I like this idea. But beside this or any other kind of optimisation, the question is why the program (the way it is right now) slows down over time?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of your problem is that line:

```
outputFile.write(firstIndexPlusOne +" "+secondIndexPlusOne+" "+parts[2]+"\n");
```

Since strings are immutable, you are cluttering the memory. Also, maybe try to flush the write buffer every turn in the loop it maybe improve a bit (my hypothesis here)

Try something like:

```
    String line = ""; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ...
    ...
      sb.append(firstIndexPlusOne);
      sb.append(" ");
      sb.append(secondIndexPlusOne);
      sb.append(" ");
      sb.append(parts[2]);
      sb.append("\n");
      outputFile.write(sb.toString());
      sb.setLength(0);
      outputFile.flush();
```

Also, maybe a good read: [Tuning Java I/O Performance (Oracle)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/perftuning-137844.html)

Comment: This made the execution much slower.

Comment: Which might be due to the flush, probably triggering real I/O, which would explain the degradation in performance. By the way, I think I've read somewhere (sorry, can't find it now) that the compiler (javac, not at runtime) actually compiles such string concatenations to the use of StringBuffers nowadays, so the bytecode of the two code snippets probably look the same, anyway.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, so this may be incorrect, but why not just write each component straight into the writer like this: `outputFile.write(firstIndexPlusOne.toString());outputFile.write(" ");` etc? There doesn't seem to be any need to construct a `StringBuilder` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think, words is meant to collect unique words, hence use Set.

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
Map<String, Integer> DIC = new HashMap<>();
```

Also DIC seems something like a frequency table, in which case `dic.keySet()` would be the same as `words`. A LinkedHashMap maintains an extra list to keep the entries sorted on order of insertion.

The writing of separate strings, instead of first creating new strings is faster.

```
   outputFile.write(firstIndexPlusOne);
   outputFile.write(" ");
   outputFile.write(secondIndexPlusOne);
   outputFile.write(" ");
   outputFile.write(parts[2]);
   outputFile.write("\n");
```

Comment: OP needs `words.indexOf(parts[0])` so making it a `Set` may not work - but a `LinkedHashSet` might be an option.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon **true**. `indexOf` is painfull too, and likely not needed, maybe some hash map will do; a second loop to create numeric indices or such.

Comment: @Joop Eggen I tested this and looks like writing like this is slightly slower.

Comment: @Meghi sorry for that; I guess the hotspot? compiler does a better job. Thanks for that bit of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

If the corpus and the word list are both sorted, the linear search performed by the words.indexOf(..) call would become slower in each iteration.

Building a HashMap(..) from your word list before processing the corpus would even things out. It might be a good idea to do so for optimization, even if that is not the problem.

Comment: No they are not sorted. It still becomes slower over time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't update neither `words` nor `DIC` in your loop, obviously the most runtime is consumed when `DIC.containsKey(parts[0]) && DIC.containsKey(parts[1])` evaluates to true.

If your question is "why is it slowing down", and not "how can I speed it up", I'd suggest that you take the first 10M lines of your file, copy them into another file and duplicate them so you receive 70M lines consisting of copies of your first 10M lines. Then, execute your code. If it slows down even though the same content is examined again and again, you may check the other answers regarding string builders and such.

If you don't experience the slowing down, then obviously it's dependent on the actual content of your 70M file. Propably, for the remaining 60M lines of your original file, `DIC.containsKey(parts[0]) && DIC.containsKey(parts[1])` evaluates to true more often and therefore the inner loop is executed more often, taking more time.

In the latter case, I doubt that you can trick the I/O load by applying single writes such that a performance gain is obtained, but of course I may be very wrong there. You'd have to try. But first, I'd recommend exploring the source of the problem, which I think lies in the file content's structure. After you understand how your code performs with respect to the input given, you may try to optimize (althoug I would try to keep the whole string in memory and write its contents in one operation after the loop instead of performing very many small write operations).

Comment: As far as I can tell, the number of containsKey hits is more or less uniformly distributed throughout the input file. I mean for instance there aren't many more hits in the fifth 10M than there are in the first 10M. Moreover, only 7% of the input data do not pass the `DIC.containsKey(parts[0]) && DIC.containsKey(parts[1])`

Comment: It seems to me the most likely cause now is the BufferedWriter starting real I/O after some time and thereby degrading performance heavily, or that in the "slow" 60M portion the words found are nearer the end of the array than they are in the first, "fast" 10M. Hence, indexOf would take longer for those. This could be found out if you copied the first 10M multiple times into a new file and see if it's faster. Of course, if it's due to I/O, you won't notice a difference... But the indices are written in your results file, are they perhaps larger when the slow 60M are evaluated?